# How to store imagefile in a table

Tags: postgresql

I have table like blow

create table txn_images(id integer   imagename  oid );

i want to insert images

my query is like

insert into txn_image values(100,lo_import('/home/ramesh/Downloads/index.jpeg'));

it through error like 
"could not open server file "index.jpeg": No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

[btea](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html)

[Large Object](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html)

use either of 1 Data-Type..

Comment: if i use bytea data type internally converted into hexadecimal.how to retrieve the image

Comment: Either one gets converted to hexadecimal encoding for output.  It is just a matter of unescaping it when it comes back.